# Can't figure out how I am supposed to define a variable

Tags: variables, pointers, struct, swap

So I have this simple function:

```
void swap(Image* v, int i, int j) {
    a = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = a;
}
```

Image* is a pointer to the struct Image and I want to swap it as you can see in the function but I can't figure out how I am supposed to define the variable "a" to make this work.

Comment: It looks as if an `Image` is a container of something. The variable `a` is an instance of that thing. Show us the definition of `Image` and we'll tell you what `a` is.

Comment: it's a struct. Look at the answer i posted below.

Comment: My comment above was mistaken-- I missed an asterisk. The way to declare `a` is `Image a;`

Comment: Looks like that's it. So simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@Beta

```
struct Image {
    String name;
    int width;
    int height;
};
typedef struct Image Image;

Image* make_image(String name, int width, int height) {
    image* image = xmalloc(sizeof(Image));
    image->name = name;
    image->last_name = width;
    image->height = height;
    return image;
}
```